# How do a load a specific drawable by using a string/int?

Tags: android, drawable

If I have a variable with the number associated with a gridview position (id int 14) how do I make the code below load the correct drawable? (ie hccat14)

```
    mBitmap = getImageFromResource(getContext(), R.drawable.hccat14,w, h);
```

Thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you are trying to use it, but it should be something like this.

```
   String resouceName = "hccat" + Integer.toString(14);
    int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName,
        "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks. :-)  I'm trying to load a specific image when a gridview cell is clicked.  This is passed as an integer.   I have my images names hccat1, hccat2, hccat3, etc.   If you can think of a better way to load specific drawable images when a certain gridview is clicked please let me know. :-)  Thanks again.

Comment: that should do it then...  The only thing I would say is that you could cache the look up if they come up repeatedly.

Comment: This worked!  The getPackageName() method didn't work, but it was fine after I typed my actual package name there instead (ie "com.my.package.name")  Thanks. :-)

Comment: Strange, I took this directly from an activity where I am using it to load a sequence of images.  Glad you got it to work!

Comment: I figure it's because it's a TileView that extends View.  getPackageName() method is probably a part of an Activity.   I'm still learning all this! :-)

Comment: yep, you are correct.  getPackageName is in Activity.  I didn't realize you weren't in your activity.

Comment: LOL... no worries.. neither did I. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use, just set the `stringName` on click

```
imageResource = Classname.this.getResources().getIdentifier(stringName,
                null, null);
        mBitmap.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

EDIT I store the image name as `packagename:drawable/imagename` in my database